# setHidden and removeFromSuperview leaves size of element

Tags: iphone

I want to hide a label if the labels text value is empty. I have no trouble checking this but if I use [label setHidden:YES] it still leaves the space.

I'm adding this label in Interface Builder by the way.

I have tried using [label setFrame: CGRectZero], but the label keeps taking up space!

What shall I do?

Comment: @Thomas, I agree, but I could not help but say that you spelled "ridiculous" wrong. :P

Comment: @Jacob - shush! :p lol... it even came up red in firefox, but I was waay to enraged to care. :p

Comment: Why is it a ridiculous question?

Comment: I want to set the Height to Zero because I have many labels under each other and if one label has no value then it shouldn't take up space.

Comment: Thank you Greg. I just can't understand why they think it's a ridiculous question... Please explain that.

Comment: its ridiculous because it shows no understanding about iphone view programming whatsoever. Do you think that upwards gravity is acting on all the elements in your view? You delete an element and it slides up to compensate? Lay your iphone on the table and you will understand. You are putting elements into the view as a 2d static grid.

Comment: I'm a ASP.NET web developer who recently made the step towards iphone development. So I thought it would happen automatically. I'm new to this, and when you're new to something, it isn't very constrictive to write "ridiculous" question, don't you think?

Comment: I'm starting to understand how the stack overflow community system works :) I've never been in this kind of forum. I understand what you mean with your comparison with position:aboslute. From now on I will create all my elements programmatically. That has to be recommended by all iphone developers that has routine? Thank you for answering by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hiding or removing a view does not affect the position of other subviews of the view's parent.

If you have a column of labels, and don't want empty labels to take up space, you will need to adjust the location of the other labels in the column to shift those below the hidden label up.

Comment: Serious... All the labels positions is made in IB. What's your recommendation when that's my case?

Comment: You'll still have to adjust their positions programatically if you want their positions to change. The springs and struts in IB control the position of the elements relative to their containing view, but not relative to each other.

Comment: Okey thanks Greg. I'm a ASP.NET-developer who recently made the step towards iphone development. So I thought it would happen automatically.